# How to calculate accurate temperature based on a sensor

Tags: microcontroller, sensor

I am writting a program which gets temperature from a QMC5883L sensor.
The sensors contains:

```
TOUT[7:0] and TOUT[15:8]
```

and it says that `The temperature coefficient is about 100 LSB/℃`.

My program looks like this:

```
int magnetometer_get_temperature() {
    uint16_t buff[2];
    magnetometer_read(MAGNETOMETR_TEMPERATURE_LSB_REGISTER, buff, 2);
    return ((int)(buff[1] | buff[0]))/100;
}
```

It does not return a correct temperature even after some hours in 23℃.

How to receive good temperature?

---

Edit after recive a hint.

This should be a correct, right?

```
int magnetometer_get_temperature() {
    uint8_t buff[2];
    magnetometer_read(MAGNETOMETR_TEMPERATURE_LSB_REGISTER, buff, 2);

    int result = (int) ((buff[1] << 8) | buff[0]);

    return (int) (result / 100) + SOME_ABSOLUTE_VALUE;
}
```

Comment: Why are you ORing them instead of concatenating them?

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply OR the two bytes together.

First byte contains the low byte and the next byte contains the following byte contains the high byte of a 16-bit result.

You need to shift or multiply the high byte to correct value to concatenate the two bytes into a 16-bit value.

Basically what it means is that if you have a little-endian MCU, you could simply read the two bytes into a 16-bit variable.

Also please note that while the value will change about 100 counts per degree, there is no offset, so you can't measure what the absolute temperature is, unless you know the offset.

Answer (score 0):

Try using float numbers.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
 

float magnetometer_get_temperature (void) 
{
 
    uint16_t buff[2];
    int a;
    float temperature;
 
    magnetometer_read(MAGNETOMETR_TEMPERATURE_LSB_REGISTER, buff, 2);
 
    a = (int) (buff[1] | buff[0]);
 
    temperature = a / 100;
 
    return temperature;
}
 
 
int main (void)
{
    float t;
 
    t = magnetometer_get_temperature();
 
    printf("The temperature is %f\n);
    
    return 0;
}
```

---

Try also to read negative temperatures because your 16-bit temperature sensor TOUT is in 2’s complement.

Comment: there isnt such thing as negative temperature.Temperature is a measure of the kinetic energy of the molecules or atoms around us it can't be negative.

Comment: The datasheet says: "Temperature Sensor Sensitivity Ta = -40°C~85°C - 100LSB/°C"